# Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/home/circleci/my-project"

Tags: angular, github, continuous-integration, circleci

I am trying to integrate simple Angular project with CircleCi. When I run  ng test, every test is passing, the project is also working fine with ng serve but when I push it to the GitHub CircleCi won't pass it because of:

> #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
>       xvfb-run -a ng test --browsers=ChromeNoSandbox --code-coverage --watch=false
>
> **Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/home/circleci/my-project".
>       Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/home/circleci/my-project".**

Here is **config.yml** file

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/my-project
    docker:
    - image: circleci/node:10.10.0-browsers
    steps:
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
        key: AngularCircleCI-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
    - run: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
    - save_cache:
        key: AngularCircleCI-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        paths:
        - "node_modules"
    - run: xvfb-run -a ng test --browsers=ChromeNoSandbox --code-coverage --watch=false
    - run: xvfb-run -a npm run e2e --protractor-config=protractor-ci.conf.js
```

And protractor-ci.conf.js

```
const config = require('./protractor.conf').config;
config.capabilities = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
};
exports.config = config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "grades-app-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.23",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "7.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.5",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.2.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.5",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

node.js version = v10.10.0
npm version = 6.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Through your terminal `cd` to your project directory folder, then type

> `ionic repair`

then follow the message info that will appear by answering the Continue? Y if you accept/ N if not. That did the job for me.

Comment: Hi mymaor89. Could you give me more details?

Comment: @Mateusz Gebroski ...when you run ionic repair in your project directory through your terminal, a message contains info will appear by what  will ionic repair do and if you accept press Y to continue or N if not.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem. My project was generated using the v1.6.0 of angular-cli.

1. `npm update -g @angular/cli`
2. editing my package.json changing the line `"@angular/cli": "1.6.0"`,
   to `"@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",`
3. `npm update` did the trick.

Comment: Thank you for response :). Unfortunately build still fails with the same error.